# how to use Gridfs mongodb in Swift

Tags: swift, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to store video using **Gridfs** in **Mongodb** from **Xcode** but I can not find any document for Swift.

Comment: How about [GridFS](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectDocs/blob/master/guide/MongoDB-GridFS.md)

Comment: yeah, this is what I need. You are a legend!!!